# How to combine variables with Python

Tags: python, string, variables, spacing

This is my problem:

```
def encrypt(mult1, mult2):
    encrypted = mult1 * mult2
    print (encrypted)
    encrypted_message = mult1, encrypted, mult2
    print (encrypt_key)
    return encrypt_key
encrypt(frst, lst)
```

On line 4 (encrypted_message = mult1, encrypted, mult2) The variable printed comes out with each of the variables spaced out, so you can tell which variable is which. How do I take away the spacing to make it appear as one variable?

Comment: it this your output ? `(331, 1871143, 5653)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following

encrypted_message = "{0}{1}{2}".format(mult1, encrypted, mult2)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `+` operator to concatenate the string

```
x = 'hello'
y = 'world'

>>> print(x+y)
helloworld
```

Comment: how did you find that its variables are string ?

Answer (score 1):

If `encrypted_message` is a tuple of 3 numbers, as I'm guessing, then you can do the following:

```
>>> encrypted_message = (4, 20, 5)
>>> ''.join(map(str, encrypted_message))
'4205'
```

You can assign that last expression to a variable or just print it directly.